# How do I use Tor with cURL (in Windows)?

Tags: windows, curl, tor

I have Vidalia installed, set up Chrome to use port 8118 for the proxy and I've checked my connection through https://check.torproject.org/ but I'm having difficulties getting this work with the command-line tool cURL. This is what I try:

```
C:\>curl -v --proxy localhost::9050 http://google.com
* About to connect() to proxy localhost port 0 (#0)
* Failed to connect to ↕: Address not available
* No error
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1: Address not available
* No error
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to ↕: Address not available
```

**Solved**:

```
curl -v --socks4a localhost:9050 http://check.torproject.org/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `--socks5` (two dashes). `-socks5` is not a valid parameter for curl, so curl is interpreting it as a hostname.

Comment: Just noticed that and changed it, now it is showing the new error, Failed to Connect.

Comment: `↕` is a weird hostname... something odd is going on.

Comment: Yep, it was the fact that I had 2 colons before the port instead of 1.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this entire mess was just syntax problems. A proper command is here:

```
curl -v --socks4a localhost:9050 http://check.torproject.org/
```

With TWO dashes before socks4a and ONE colon before the port.

Answer (score 2):

More updated response using `socks5`.

```
curl -v --socks5 localhost:9150 http://check.torproject.org/
```

So, using `port 9150` for socks 5.