# How to use Tor socks5 in R getURL

Tags: r, curl, proxy, socks, tor

I want to use Tor in `getURL` function in R. Tor is working (checked in firefox), `socks5` at `port 9050`. But when I set this in R, I get the following error

```
html <- getURL("http://www.google.com", followlocation = T, .encoding="UTF-8", .opts = list(proxy = "127.0.0.1:9050", timeout=15))
```

> Error in curlPerform(curl = curl, .opts = opts, .encoding = .encoding) : 
>        '\n\nTor is not an HTTP Proxy\n\n\n
>
> ## Tor is not an HTTP Proxy
>
> \n
>
> \nIt appears you have configured your web browser to use Tor as an HTTP proxy.\nThis is not correct: Tor is a SOCKS proxy, not an HTTP proxy.\nPlease configure your client accordingly.

I've tried replace proxy with socks, socks5 but it didn't work.

Comment: Can you include your call that used socks5? Looks like that might be the answer, based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167166/how-do-i-use-tor-with-curl-in-windows).

Comment: I did. Look at the end of the first line. 127.0.0.1:9050 is the socks5

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are [curl bindings for R](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RCurl/index.html), after which you can use curl to call the Tor SOCKS5 proxy server.

The call from the shell (which you can translate to the R binding) is:

`curl --socks5-hostname 127.0.0.1:9050 google.com`

Tor will do the DNS also for A records.

Answer (score 7):

RCurl will default to a HTTP proxy, but Tor provides a SOCKS proxy. Tor is clever enough to understand that the proxy client (RCurl) is trying to use a HTTP proxy, hence the error message in HTML returned by Tor.

In order to get RCurl, and curl, to use a SOCKS proxy, you can use a protocol prefix, and there are two protocol prefixes for SOCKS5: "socks5" and "socks5h" (see [the Curl manual](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#--socks5-hostname)). The latter will let the SOCKS server handle DNS-queries, which is the preferred method when using Tor (in fact, Tor will warn you if you let the proxy client resolve the hostname).

Here is a pure R solution which will use Tor for dns-queries.

```
library(RCurl)
options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050"))
my.handle <- getCurlHandle()
html <- getURL(url='https://www.torproject.org', curl=my.handle)
```

If you want to specify additional parameters, see below on where to put them:

```
library(RCurl)
options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy = "socks5h://127.0.0.1:9050",
                            useragent = "Mozilla",
                            followlocation = TRUE,
                            referer = "",
                            cookiejar = "my.cookies.txt"
                            )
        )
my.handle <- getCurlHandle()
html <- getURL(url='https://www.torproject.org', curl=my.handle)
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Naparst I would really appreciate a hint on how to do the solution you propose
option should be something like :
opts <- list(socks5.hostname="127.0.0.1:9050")
(this doesn't work since socks5.hostname is not an option)

Answer (score 2):

Under Mac OSX install [Tor Bundle for Mac](https://www.torproject.org/download/download-easy.html.en) and [Privoxy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ijbswa/files/Macintosh%20%28OS%20X%29/3.0.21%20%28stable%29/) and then update the proxy settings in the system preferences.

'System preferences' --> 'Wi-FI' --> 'Advanced' --> 'Proxies' --> set 'Web Proxy (HTTP)' Web Proxy Server 127.0.0.1:8118

'System preferences' --> 'Wi-FI' --> 'Advanced' --> 'Proxies' --> set 'Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS)' Secure Web Proxy Server 127.0.0.1:8118 --> 'OK' --> 'Apply'

```
library(rcurl)
curl <- getCurlHandle()
curlSetOpt(proxy='127.0.0.1:9150',proxytype=5,curl=curl)
html <- getURL(url='check.torproject.com',curl=curl)
```