# Is there a way to tell R to use sock5 for connecting to a remote PostgresDB?

Tags: r

I'm looking for the environment vars to make R use the following packages with a sock5 proxy.

install.packages("RPostgres")
library(DBI)

Normally with http/https I can pass the http_proxy or https_proxy vars.  How would you force a sock5 proxy?

Comment: Could this help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925234/how-to-use-tor-socks5-in-r-geturl ?

Comment: Will try!  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This does not work. I was able to setup socat and get things working.  Thx for the post.